# quartz - java.lang.ClassCastException org.quartz.JobDetail cannot be cast to ScheduledJobDetail with JobStoreTX

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, classcastexception

I'm using quartz 1.6.5. I recently moved from Quartz Job Store from RamJobStore to org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX. Since this, I've started to see **ClassCastException** in my log whenever quartz tries to run a job.

```
Jul 26, 2010 3:10:00 AM org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger schedulerError
SEVERE: Job (group52.52 threw an exception.
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.quartz.JobDetail cannot be cast to ScheduledJobDetail]
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.quartz.JobDetail cannot be cast to ScheduledJobDetail
        at ScheduledJob.execute(ScheduledJob.java:150)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
        ... 1 more
```

My quartz.properties looks like:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = DefaultQuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction = false
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS
org.quartz.dataSource.dsjta.jndiURL=myDs
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=true
```

I initialize my scheduler using the following code:

`org.quartz.Scheduler quartzScheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory("quartz.properties").getScheduler();`

The same code works with a RAMJobStore but not with a JobStoreTX. What could I be missing here?
I enabled logging and this is what I find in the logs:

```
136672 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.SimpleSemaphore  - Lock 'TRIGGER_ACCESS' is desired by: DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread
136672 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.SimpleSemaphore  - Lock 'TRIGGER_ACCESS' is being obtained: DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread
136672 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.SimpleSemaphore  - Lock 'TRIGGER_ACCESS' given to: DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread
136703 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.SimpleSemaphore  - Lock 'TRIGGER_ACCESS' retuned by: DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread
136703 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory  - Producing instance of Job 'group152.152', class=ScheduledJob
136703 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3] DEBUG org.quartz.core.JobRunShell  - Calling execute on job group152.152
136703 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3] ERROR org.quartz.core.JobRunShell  - Job group152.152 threw an unhandled Exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.quartz.JobDetail cannot be cast to ScheduledJobDetail
        at ScheduledJob.execute(SchedulerQuartzImpl.java:150)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
136703 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3] ERROR org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger  - Job (group152.152 threw an exception.
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.quartz.JobDetail cannot be cast to ScheduledJobDetail]
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:227)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.quartz.JobDetail cannot be cast to ScheduledJobDetail
        at ScheduledJob.execute(SchedulerQuartzImpl.java:150)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
        ... 1 more
136703 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3] DEBUG org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.SimpleSemaphore  - Lock 'TRIGGER_ACCESS' is desired by: DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3
136703 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3] DEBUG org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.SimpleSemaphore  - Lock 'TRIGGER_ACCESS' is being obtained: DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3
```

Update: I tried the same with org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT and still the same issue persists.

Comment: What is `ScheduledJobDetail`? There's no such class in the Quartz API.

Comment: ScheduledJobDetail is a class we wrote which extends org.quartz.JobDetail and adds a few fields for our convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely to be that you have subclassed `JobDetail`.

When you used `RAMJobStore`, your `ScheduledJobDetail` objects would have been kept in memory, and so you could cast back from `JobDetail` without a problem. When using a database `JobStore`, though, Quartz will be reconstructing the `JobDetail` objects itself, and it has no way of knowing that you want it to use a custom class for this, and so you get the exception.

Even if Quartz did know to use a `ScheduledJobDetail`, it would have no way of handling the additional fields you added.

Subclassing `JobDetail` is not the way to go. You need to find some other way of encoding this information, without subclassing.